# Angular NGX Datatable data not set

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

I'm new on angular, i try to set data from the module.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.populate();
  }

  public populate() {
    this.productService.getAllProduct('6f453f89-274d-4462-9e4b-c42ae60344e4').subscribe(prod => {
      this.products = prod.map(prx => prx.request);
      console.log(this.products);
    });
```

html

```
    <ngx-datatable style="height: 500px; box-shadow: none" class="material fullscreen" [columnMode]="'force'"
                [headerHeight]="50" [footerHeight]="50" [rowHeight]="60" [scrollbarV]="true" [rows]="products">
                <ngx-datatable-column name="name">
                    <ng-template ngx-datatable-header-template>
                        Name
                    </ng-template>
                </ngx-datatable-column>
</ngx-datatable>
```

but the data doesn't show. i try to check it on console.log, the data appear on console.log(this.products). i don't know what's wrong on it. i added some code on my constructor.

```
constructor(private productService: ProductService, public modalService: NgbModal) {
    this.products = [new Product()];
  }
```

the code work, but the datatable show an empty row before the data filled.

Comment: Are you using @swimlane-ngxdatatable or ngx-datatable?

Answer (score 0):

Does "name" exists as a property on the products?

If not, you can either change the `name="name"` attribute to the correct prop or you need add something like this (with `differenProp` being whatever the correct prop holding the name is):

```
...
<ng-template ngx-datatable-header-template>
  Name
</ng-template>
<ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-row="row" let-value="value">
  {{ row.differenProp }}
</ng-template>
...
```